# global menu in kubuntu not working with firefox

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I switched to Kubuntu only recently and find the global menu a very intriguing feature.
However, upon setting it up, I discovered that firefox does not support it, which is a bust, as I rely on FF while working.

So I googled and found this (https://blog.broulik.de/2018/03/gtk-global-menu/) and some other posts on reddit etc. that.

However, I did not find any way to install it and test it out. So is there either a way to install it from a repo, is there a solution in FF or can anyone assist me in installing gmenu-dbusmenu-proxy on my machine?

thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. This website is oriented to developers and programming, and your question doesn't seem to meet any of those aspects. Maybe you should consider other websites in the StackExchange network, like https://askubuntu.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Not too sure if this will work as I do not have enough information about your setup, or the cause of your issue. But I'm currently running Kubuntu 20.04, and have encountered the same problem. It was solved by going to firefox settings -> customize and checking "Title Bar" in the bottom left corner.